# React Native on iOS returns HTTP 406 Not Acceptable error message

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, swift2

I'm trying to show a React Native view in my iOS application using Swift 2. React Native returns the HTTP 406 Not Acceptable error message.

```
let bridge = RCTBridge(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleProvider: nil, launchOptions: ["controller":self])
let reactRootView: RCTRootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: moduleName, initialProperties: initialProperties)
reactRootView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
reactRootView.delegate = self
let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.view.addSubview(reactRootView)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Could you suggest a decision to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the failure: a wrong JS code location URL.